# Latex errors with \begin{theorem}

Tags: errors, theorems

I am trying to create a new theorem in a tex document, but I keep getting an error. Here is the code I am currently using

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.25in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{.25in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.4in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}

\newtheorem{theorem}[Theorem]



\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    My Tex doesn't work
\end{theorem}


\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this, I get three errors.

> Paragraph ended before \@ynthm was complete.
>
> Environment theorem
>   undefined. \begin{theorem}
>
> \begin{document} ended by
>   \end{theorem}. \end{theorem}

I am assuming the last error is a direct consequence of `\begin{theorem}` not being recognized, so if I can solve the first two errors, I think I will be okay.

I have tried changing `\newtheorem{theorem}[Theorem]` to `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[Theorem]` to no avail, and changed `\begin{theorem}` to `\begin{theorem}[Theorem]` again with no positive result.

Any ideas would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Also don't set `\oddsidemargin` etc. directly. Use the `geometry` package for this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of `\newtheorem` can be confusing:

See the `amsthm` documentation for more detailled explanation but in short it's like this:

Use

- `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` if `theorem` shall be the counter (it's defined then, and `Theorem` is the environment name.)
- `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[foo]` if `Theorem` should be the environment name and `foo` is an existing counter that shall be used as the reset driver
- `\newtheorem{theorem}[foobar]{Theorem}` if `foobar` is a different counter that already exists and should be used for counting.

In any case: `\newtheorem{theoremenvironment}{Environmentname}` is mandatory. This was missing in the OP.

The precise behaviour depends on the position of the optional argument (or if it is used at all ;-))

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{hyperref}


%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.25in}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{.25in}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
%\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.4in}
%\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}



\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    My Tex does work now
\end{theorem}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Once the minimum time has elapsed, I will accept this answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: Perhaps better to explain that `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` generates a new counter, `theorem` that can then be used in other `\newtheorem` declarations `\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}`

Comment: @daleif: See my additions right at the top ;-) I was posting it while you were 'complaining' ;-)

Comment: I would remove the `\newcounter` stuff from the MWE, as it will confuse more users than it will help

Comment: the documentation for `amsthm` (`texdoc amsthm`) has a pretty cogent explanation of how the arguments in braces and brackets are supposed to work.  that is, if you have the documentation that was totally rewritten in 2015.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That's rather meant for the O.P. actually, I assume. I know about the order of arguments

Comment: @daleif: `amsthm` is confusing ;-)